# What's the runtime complexity of the method "replacingOccurrences(of:with:)" in swift

Tags: swift, big-o

I have this line of code.

```
var formatted = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")
```

and I want to know what is the time complexity of that method, it's not on the developer apple documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be `O(n)`, cuz you need to run for all elements, and replacing is constant time operating.